# Unable to run the shell script from Dockerfile which container some stdin to complete the script

Tags: dockerfile

hello i have script called `postrun.sh` when we run same script so it aks for user input to run the script , user required to provide  yes , enter , yes

i have docker file

```
FROM centos:latest
RUN useradd jenkins -u 1001
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
RUN mkdir /opt/SOAtest
RUN mkdir /opt/SOAtest/parasoft
ADD epel.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
ADD RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7  /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/
RUN yum -y clean all
#RUN yum -y install wget
ADD parasoft_soatest_9.7_linux_20140227.sh  /opt/SOAtest/
RUN chmod +x /opt/SOAtest/parasoft_soatest_9.7_linux_20140227.sh
RUN cd  /opt/SOAtest/parasoft
RUN echo "1/yes" | postrun.sh
```

error which i am getting  while building docker image

```
**Step 12/12 : RUN echo "1/yes" |     ./parasoft_soatest_9.7_linux_20140227.sh
 ---> Running in 973ce094358a


/bin/sh: ./parasoft_soatest_9.7_linux_20140227.sh: No such file or directory

The command '/bin/sh -c echo "1/yes" | ./parasoft_soatest_9.7_linux_20140227.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127**
```

Comment: Hi Atul, welcome to SO. Please take a moment and look into this, especially regarding formatting and proof reading your posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Atul,

bash gives you answer: "No such file or directory" and error code 127.
Are you sure that you are in right directory?

First you have this:

```
ADD parasoft_soatest_9.7_linux_20140227.sh  /opt/SOAtest/
```

then you

```
cd  /opt/SOAtest/parasoft
```

and execute postrun.sh

I will repeat my question: are you sure that you have Parasoft SOAtest installation file in /opt/SOAtest/parasoft directory?

Comment: BTW Atul, did you check SOAtest installation guide? Please check section "Preconfiguring SOAtest During Installation" which could make you process easier.